# Apply a function with Monadic result instead of a function with a non-Monadic result

Tags: haskell

I have a function (from a library) that accepts another function as an argument:
`func :: ( a -> b ) -> a -> m()`

But now, I want to apply a function that produces a Monadic result to `func`:
`funcArg :: a -> m b`

So `func` would actually need to be `func :: ( a -> mb ) -> a -> m()`

I have a feeling that `func` could be lifted into `m` and the resulting `m ( m() )` can be turned into the needed `m()`. But I'm really just guessing at this point.

How would I go about this? Any hint is highly appreciated.

**Edit:**
The type signature that I've given is not accurate. It should be `func :: ( a -> b ) -> c -> m()`. The concrete signature is for the animate function in Gloss `animate :: Display -> Color -> ( Float -> Picture ) -> IO()`. While my function has the signature `( Float -> IO Picture )`. The correct function to use in this case is `animateIO`.

Comment: I don't really believe this type signature. No interesting functions of type `(a -> b) -> a -> m ()` exist. Such a type could be *part* of some larger type signature, but it would mean something different depending on how it was embedded. So, please include the function's actual, full signature; your attempt to simplify has instead obscured.

Comment: If type b can be anything (unrelated to m), it can as well be written as  `m b`. Besides, joining two levels of monad into a single one is what monads are for: [library function `join`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join)

Comment: To get a useful answer here, I think you'll need to tell us what the library function actually is and/or give its full type signature, as well as the full type signature of the function you're trying to pass to it.

Comment: It is certainly not generally the case that you can take a function `(a -> b) -> m c` and convert it to a function `(a -> m b) -> m d`.

Comment: I'm experimenting with Gloss. I'm still trying to wrap my head around certain concepts in Haskell. The `animate` function has a signature `Display -> Color -> ( Float -> Picture ) -> IO()`. My animate function produces an `IO Picture` though and I wondered if it is possible to still use it. In the meantime I've stumbled upon the `animateIO` function which indeed accepts `( Float -> IO Picture )`. For my particular application that should work. From the comments so far, it seems like there is no general way to do what I'd asked.

Comment: I think part of the confusion here is regarding type variables. These are any names in a type that start with a lowercase letter. Consider the type signature `f :: a -> b`. There are two type variables in it: `a` and `b`. The body of `f` must work for *any* choice of `a` and `b`.  In fact, note that there is no (useful) implementation of `f` that fits the signature I've given! Also note that there is only one implementation of `g :: a -> a` (ignoring infinite loops, etc). The type signatures in the question are far more general than the real ones you're dealing with. Too general to implement.

Comment: There is not, unfortunately. You can play with fire in the form of `unsafePerformIO`, but that road leads only to dismay and nightmares. Either the library authors *should* have included an `IO` version (which it sounds like, from the comments, they did), or there's a good reason they didn't (maybe something complex with threading or sequencing of results prevents them from doing so). Either way, the answer in the case of the `IO` monad is "No"

Comment: I tried answering this question with an unsafe operation.  I recant and have deleted the answer.  I will try `gloss` for myself and see what I can find.